# How to implement error handling on a loop containing dictionary?

Tags: python

How do I implement error-handling in this loop?
My loop contains a literal dictionary of words (keys) and its description (values).

```
wordList = input("Please enter a word to search for")

isWordSearched = False

for word in glossary:
  wordlist == word['term']
    print (word['term'] + " " + "is" + " " + word['description'])
    isWordSearched = True

if isWordSearched == False:
  print("Searched word is not in the glossary")
```

Comment: would you mind including the code not as a image but as text, so you facilitate people answering your question?

Comment: What type of errors do you expect in the provided script? I personally do not see any possible errors with this short script, except that you missed an `if` key word before `wordList == word['term']:`

Comment: how do I add exception blocks inside this loop? With try: and except: Thanks

Also, I couldn't write the code, the post was giving me errors and this is my first time using stack. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are just missing the `if` on the `wordList == word['term']`.

```
if wordList == word['term']:
```

But if you really want to add try catch block (coz' you might have KeyError if the key is not in the dict), you can try this:

```
for word in glossary:
    try:
        if wordList == word['term']:
            print(...)
            isWordSearched = True
    except:
        break
```

**NOTE**: next time, please include the code of your question as text to make it easy to debug your code.

Comment: how do I add exception blocks inside this loop?

try:

except:

Thanks